# Убрать пробелы в jquery/преобразовать в строку

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте. В общем я получил строку в jquery

```
var string=$(this).parents('#comments').find("#showName").html().split(',');
```

И пытаюсь передать эту строку через ajax.

```
data: {'name': string[0]},
```

Так вот, и получаю ответ от сервера, что такие данные я передаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как преобразовать это строку в более корректную? То есть убрать пробелы, судя по всему.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Update: Проблему решил, оказывается была проблема в самом html

Comment: Вы вместо `var_dump` в `php` сделайте лучше `console.log($string)` вашего. И вместо `$string` объявите переменную так: `var string=...`

Comment: Извиите, возможно неуместный вопрос. Вы действительно получаете в ответ от сервера картинку?

Comment: @0xdb Не просто картинку, а картинку результата функции `var_dump`!

Comment: Лучше бы помогли, а не до слов докапывались. Сфотографировал ответ.

Comment: @Nikita111 Посмотрите ещё раз мой первый комментарий, и дополните свой вопрос результатами из `console.log`

Comment: Тоже самое. https://imgur.com/a/RpKPr (то что два раза одно и тоже слово, так и надо). Пробелы убрать как-то надо. Объявлено var string.
По привычке $ написал тут

Comment: @Nikita111 Я и помогаю вам. С ajax правда помочь не могу,  но на качественный вопрос вы быстрее получите ответ.

Comment: Мне не на ajax ответ нужен, а как с такой строки 
 ["↵(тут пробел) Nikola@mail.ru", " Nikola@mail.ru"]
Удалить пробелы корректно

Answer (score 2):

Я просто оставлю [это](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) здесь

Тут же пример использования

```
var str = "       Hello World!       ";
    alert(str.trim());
```

Comment: Спасибо, но проблема была в другом.Нашел уже, обрезать не надо